# Several forms on a page

Tags: django, forms, validation, save

I'm relatively new to Django and trying to create a page, where I ask questions and allow users to give two answer. So I want to display a list of questions, and fields for two guesses below. I tried to make using form, but I can't save or validate the data I get from those forms.
Below if my relevant code.

**From models.py:**

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    subject = models.FloatField(verbose_name='ID')

class SubjectForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.FloatField()

class General(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    answer = models.FloatField()

class Guess(models.Model):
    general = models.ForeignKey(General)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    lower = models.FloatField('lower boundary')
    upper = models.FloatField('upper boundary')

class GuessForm(forms.Form):
    lower = forms.FloatField()
    upper = forms.FloatField()
```

**From views.py:**

```
def questions(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If answers were submitted
        for question in all_questions:
            form = GuessForm()

            if form.is_valid():
                lower = request.POST.get('lower','')
                upper = request.POST.get('upper','')
                new_guess = Guess(pk = 'question',
                    subject = subject,
                    lower = lower,
                    upper = upper)
                new_quess.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/general_knowledge/questions/thanks/')
            else:
                form = GuessForm()
                csrfContext = RequestContext(request,{'form': form})

                return render_to_response('general_knowledge/question_form.html',
                    {'all_questions': all_questions},
                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**From template**

```
{% for question in all_questions %}
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <ol>
            <p><LI> {{ question.question }}.</p>
            <label for="lower">Lower boundary:</label><input type="text" name="lower">
            {{ form.lower.errors }}
            <label for="upper">Upper boundary: </label><input type="text" name="upper">
            {{ form.upper.errors }}
        </ol>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use JQuery to print the validation when submit, something like this :

```
$("input[type="submit"]).click(function () {
        if ($("#lower").text() == // some condition
        {
            $("#validation").show();
        }
        else {
            $("Form").submit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Despite the acceptance, I can’t see how that answers the question as written. The question’s asking about how to validate and save form data in Django. jQuery validation on the client-side would be a fine addition, but it’s not what the question is about.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite If this is what helped her in the end - she probably didn't need more than that. It's better than 0 answers, and if you have a more correct answer, I'll be glad if you write it.